# MySQL: WHERE ... IN()

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * from movies
 INNER JOIN movie_genres ON movies.id_movie=movie_genres.fk_id_movie
 INNER JOIN genres ON movie_genres.fk_id_genre=genres.id_genre
WHERE genre_name IN ('action','crime');
```

movie_genres has just 2 columns (FK):
 - fk_id_movie
 - fk_id_genre

[movies]--------[movies_genres]-------[genres]

This returns an **OR** result: any movie which genre is 'action' OR 'crime';

Is it possible to write this with an AND result. Return only movies that have the 2 genres altogether?

Comment: What columns are in your `movie_genres` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  A good way to do this is with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
SELECT *
from movies INNER JOIN
     movie_genres
     ON movies.id=id_movie
GROUP BY movies.id
HAVING sum(genre = '1') > 0 and
       sum(genre = '2') > 0 and
       sum(genre = '3') > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks. That's it! As movie_genres doesn't have any columns other than the 2 Foreign keys, it have to be **grouped** and **summed** in order to work out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use the AND keyword...

```
SELECT * from movies INNER JOIN movie_genres ON movies.id=id_movie WHERE (genre = 1 AND genre = 2 AND genre = 3);
```

Comment: This will always return an empty result - a genre cannot be both '1' and '2' in a single row.

Answer (score 1):

What your query does is to join a single line of `movies` with a single row of `movie_genres` and then evaluate it - which, as you suggested, is not the result you're expecting.
Instead, you need to build some query which joins `movies` with some aggregation of `movie_genres`.

Gordon's answer is a great example of this. A different approach, assuming the combination of `id_movie` and `genre` is unique, is to count how many of the genres your movie matches:

```
SELECT *
FROM movies 
INNER JOIN (SELECT    id_movie, COUNT(*) AS matches
            FROM      movie_genres
            WHERE     genre IN ('1', '2', '3')
            GROUP  BY id_movie) genres ON movies.id=id_movie
WHERE      matches = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from movies INNER JOIN movie_genres
ON movies.id=id_movie  WHERE genre IN ('1','2','3')
GROUP BY movies.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT genre)= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only select the columns you need, not all of them (*) unless you really need every single column of both tables in your results. It's better for performance.

```
SELECT movies.col1, movies.col2 
FROM `movies` 
    INNER JOIN `movie_genres` ON movies.id = movie_genres.id_movie 
GROUP BY movies.id
HAVING SUM( DISTINCT movie_genres.genre ) = 6
```

Comment: And what if the movie has genres `1` and `5` ?

Comment: That could be a problem you're right, but we don't know his data model, and honestly I don't think this seems like the best way of managing a movies/genres relationship - as the `id_movie` that is showing up indicates that each genre has a movie ID attached to it, I think a `movies`, `movies_genres` and `genres` table would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from movies
where id in 
(
select movie_id from 
movie_genres group by genre having count(genre) = 3
)
```